# UISearchController: indexPath doesn't change with original array

Tags: swift

It's easier to explain by example. I have original array which is searched and filtered array with searched items. If i found one item after searching and tap on it, i mark it as done (I have todo list), but when i cancel my search, I find that the first element in the original array is marked, not the third item.
I googled some threads and found almost similar problems, but solutions doesn't suit to my problem. For example:
[didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexpath after filter UISearchController - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855457/didselectrowatindexpath-indexpath-after-filter-uisearchcontroller-swift)

And here some code. Especially at `didSelectRowAt` I mark the items to done. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
private var searchBarIsEmpty: Bool {
    guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return false }
    return text.isEmpty
}
private var isFiltering: Bool {
    return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering {
        return filteredTasks?.count ?? 0
    }
    return manager.tasks.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Keys.cell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ToDoCell
    var currentItem: Task
    if isFiltering {
        currentItem = filteredTasks?[indexPath.row] ?? manager.tasks[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        currentItem = manager.tasks[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = currentItem.taskName
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = currentItem.description

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let accessoryType: UITableViewCell.AccessoryType = manager.changeState(at: indexPath.row) ? .checkmark : .none
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = accessoryType
}
```

Comment: You need to save the checked/unchecked status in your model.

Comment: it's not main problem. I have edit and delete features and what to do with them? I have similar problem.

Comment: Apparently the *manager* doesn’t know anything about the `filteredTasks`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use tableView.dequeueReusableCell, you may get the old cell, so you should update it. You should read [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell).

@PGDev already said in comments that you should save checked/unchecked status in your model.

I hope my example will help you.

You can contain state of cells in cell models:

```
class YourCellModel {

    var task: Task
    var checked: Bool

    init(task: Task, checked: Bool) {
        self.task = task
        self.checked = checked
    }

}
```

And add it in `ToDoCell`:

```
//...
var model: YourCellModel {
    didSet {
        updateViews()
    }
}

func updateViews() {
    titleLabel.text = task.taskName
    descriptionLabel.text = task.description
    if model.checked {
        //...
    } else {
        //....
    }
}
```

And update model here:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Keys.cell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ToDoCell
    // You should contain cell models to remember their states
    let model = cellModels[indexPath.row]
    cell.model = model
    return cell
}
```

When the user checks a cell, you should save it in your cell model. You can do it in `ToDoCell`:

```
func checked() {
    model.checked = true
}
```

Note: If `isFiltering` is true, it is a different array of cell models.

UPD. I noticed your `Task` is similar to a cell model. You can save `checked` status there. But your cell should have access to it.

Comment: but i don't have access to specific task in ToDoCell

Comment: @SilentKunZ You update states of cells using tasks (it is here: `cell.titleLabel.text = currentItem.taskName //...`. I just moved it to the cell model. Your `Task` seems to be a cell model. You can save checked status there.